# QT TableWidget updating MySql table

Tags: mysql, pyqt, qtablewidget

I have already got the info to my tablewidget, then i edit the cells of my table and i connect the function below to a pushbutton, however when i press the button to update i get this:

ine 653, in update_table
with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'connection'

def update_table(self):
# Connect to the MySQL database
connection = pymysql.connect(
host='localhost',
user='####',
password='######',
database='#####'
)

```
    table_data = []
    table = self.tableWidget_4
    try:
        # Execute the SQL update queries for each cell in the QTableWidget
        with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
            for row in range(self.tableWidget_4.rowCount()):
                afm_item = self.tableWidget_4.item(row, 0)
                afm = afm_item.text()

                for column in range(1, self.tableWidget_4.columnCount()):
                    item = self.tableWidget_4.item(row, column)
                    value = item.text()
                    column_name = self.tableWidget_4.horizontalHeaderItem(column).text()

                    # Construct and execute the update query
                    update_query = f"UPDATE pelates SET {column_name} = %s WHERE afm = %s"
                    cursor.execute(update_query, (value, afm))

            # Commit the changes to the database
            self.connection.commit()

            print("Table updated successfully!")

    except pymysql.Error as e:
        print(f"Error occurred while updating table: {e}")
```

Comment: Please provide a valid [mre].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.